# Import media to online WordPress from local development

Tags: theme-development, media-library, import

I have a site being developed locally and I want to import the contents to an online installation. I used wordpress "import" but it cant get the media files. Is there any "wordpress" was of doing this or will I have to get access to my LDE from outside or upload the entire installation which I would rather avoid?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When I use WordPress Import in this cases, this is what I do:

- Export the XML in localhost.
- Open the exported file in a text editor.
- Search and replace `http://localhost/wp-content/uploads/` for `http://example.com/custom-temporary-folder/`.
- Upload the `uploads` folder via FTP to the `custom-temporary-folder`.
- Perform the Import in `example.com` using the modified XML file.

Comment: very clever ... will give it a go.

Comment: ... worked perfect ... great technique!

Comment: Do you need to tick the checkbox "Download and import image attachments"?

Comment: I did it by ticking the checbox. Media got imported. But I am not sure what it does :)

Comment: Wow. I'm really glad to have stumbled across this answer. I thought I had it cracked by finding and replacing all the URLs for those in the uploads directory on the new server but I guess the import process doesn't like them being in there already. Adding to temp folder worked like a charm.